# How to search item in DataTables with specific class?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have data with DataTable. I want to create a button that when I click on him it will filter all the `td` that have `div` with the class "yellow". 
I have this code:

```
 var clients_table = $("#clients_table").DataTable();
 clients_table.column(2).search($("div.yellow"));
```

But this is not correct. Any idea?

Comment: what function do you mean by filter.

Comment: I mean that the function filter will show me only the item that have wrap div with class "yellow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want complex filtering on CSS or attributes you will need to create a [custom search filter](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search) yourself. To filter out all rows where the third column not have a class `.yellow` you can do this :

```js
var filter = function(settings, searchData, index, rowData) {
  var $td = table.row(index).nodes().to$().find('td:eq(2)');
  return $td.find('.yellow').length;
}
```

Turn the filter on (for example in a click event click event) :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(filter);
table.draw();
```

Turn it off :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
table.draw();
```

small demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7aLptLve/**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("td div.yellow").each(function() {

    //write your logic here

});
```

Comment: This is right, but I want this will be in search function of DataTable